# Set title (color/font)of UINavigation controller at the same time (strange behaviour)

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uinavigationbar

I'm getting some strange behaviour when i'm trying to customize the look of the UINavigation controller in the app delegate.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 20)!]

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 173/255, blue: 173/255, alpha: 1)]
```

Whenever I set the color first the font doesn't change, and when i set the font first, the color and the font don't change. However If I set the fond on its own then it changes... I can't seem to do both at the same time. Is there another way i'm supposed to be doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing it twice you are undoing the first one. You need to do it like this...

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 173/255, blue: 173/255, alpha: 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing both at the same time, you are doing one and then **replacing** this first with the second.

It is really no different that `i=1;` followed by `i=2;`.

The definition:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes
```

You need to add all the attributes to a `NSDictionary` and set the `titleTextAttributes` once.

Comment: Oh okk. I see that now.